# ajax, jquery contact form with reCAPTCHA v2 - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, recaptcha

I have a jquery/ajax contact form and tried to add the Google reCAPTCHA v2, but it isn't working. The form worked before I included the reCAPTCHA. The reCAPTCHA shows up (although it takes forever to load), and I can verify that I'm not a robot (which takes forever as well), but when I click on my submit button, the spot where I display my status messages shows this, including the code, as text:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"> <html><head> <title>500 Internal Server Error</title> </head><body> <h1>Internal Server Error</h1> <p>The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.</p> <p>Please contact the server administrator, and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.</p> <p>More information about this error may be available in the server error log.</p> </body></html>
```

I can't figure out what's going wrong. I followed Google's instructions and included this just before my  tag:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

and integrated my form like this:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeehAsUAAAAAILDfzizJ23GHH7yPGxWBFP_3tE7"></div>
```

I tried many different ways to integrate it in my mailer.php file without success, and I couldn't find many tutorials that address v2 specifically (not sure if it even matters). My most recent version of the mailer.php is based on an [example](https://github.com/google/recaptcha/blob/master/examples/example-captcha.php) I found on [Google's recaptcha Github](https://github.com/google/recaptcha):

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . 'inc/autoload.php';
// If the form was submitted    
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

  // If the Google Recaptcha box was clicked
  if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
        $siteKey = '6LeehAsUAAAAAILDfzizJ23GHH7yPGxWBFP_3tE7';
        $secret = 'I-removed-this-for-now';
        $recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($secret);            
        $resp = $recaptcha->verify($gRecaptchaResponse, $remoteIp);

        // If the Google Recaptcha check was successful
        if ($resp->isSuccess()){
            $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
            $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
            $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
            $message = trim($_POST["message"]);
            if ( empty($name) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                http_response_code(400);
                echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
                exit;
            }
            $recipient = "I-removed-this@for-now.com";
            $subject = "New message from $name";
            $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
            $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
            $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";
            $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";
            if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
                http_response_code(200);
                echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
            } 

            else {
                http_response_code(500);
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong, and we couldn't send your message. Check your email address.";
            }

        } 

        // If the Google Recaptcha check was not successful    
        else {
            echo "Robot verification failed. Please try again.";
        }

    } 

    // If the Google Recaptcha box was not clicked   
    else {
        echo "Please click the reCAPTCHA box.";
    }      

} 

// If the form was not submitted
// Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.         
else {
    http_response_code(403);
    echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
}      
?>
```

This is the app.js that goes with my contact form (I haven't changed this at all when trying to include the reCAPTCHA):

```
$(function() {

    // Get the form.
    var form = $('#ajax-contact');

    // Get the messages div.
    var formMessages = $('#form-messages');

    // Set up an event listener for the contact form.
    $(form).submit(function(e) {
        // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
        e.preventDefault();

        // Serialize the form data.
        var formData = $(form).serialize();

        // Submit the form using AJAX.
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            data: formData
        })
        .done(function(response) {
            // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
            $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
            $(formMessages).addClass('success');

            // Set the message text.
            $(formMessages).text(response);

            // Clear the form.
            $('#name').val('');
            $('#email').val('');
            $('#message').val('');
        })
        .fail(function(data) {
            // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
            $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
            $(formMessages).addClass('error');

            // Set the message text.
            if (data.responseText !== '') {
                $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
            } else {
                $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured, and your message could not be sent.');
            }
        });

    });

});
```

The autoload.php comes directly from the Google Github, and I didn't make any changes:

```
<?php

/* An autoloader for ReCaptcha\Foo classes. This should be required()
 * by the user before attempting to instantiate any of the ReCaptcha
 * classes.
 */

spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    if (substr($class, 0, 10) !== 'ReCaptcha\\') {
      /* If the class does not lie under the "ReCaptcha" namespace,
       * then we can exit immediately.
       */
      return;
    }

    /* All of the classes have names like "ReCaptcha\Foo", so we need
     * to replace the backslashes with frontslashes if we want the
     * name to map directly to a location in the filesystem.
     */
    $class = str_replace('\\', '/', $class);

    /* First, check under the current directory. It is important that
     * we look here first, so that we don't waste time searching for
     * test classes in the common case.
     */
    $path = dirname(__FILE__).'/'.$class.'.php';
    if (is_readable($path)) {
        require_once $path;
    }

    /* If we didn't find what we're looking for already, maybe it's
     * a test class?
     */
    $path = dirname(__FILE__).'/../tests/'.$class.'.php';
    if (is_readable($path)) {
        require_once $path;
    }
});
```

I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: ok, sorry, I've been away from PHP too long - or to put it another way, thank god I've been away from PHP for a long time :p

Comment: It's what I took from the Google example. The class is defined in the autoload.php, which also comes from Github. Did I include it incorrectly?

Comment: I'll remove my comment, I thought the backslash was wrong, but apparently that's somehow valid syntax in PHP

Comment: What's the value of this `$(form).attr('action')`  before making ajax call ?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if I got some kind of punctuation in the code wrong... or something else. I'm not good with PHP.

Comment: @Nandan I'm not really sure what you mean. I wrapped my form in this: <form id="ajax-contact" class="contact-form" role="form"  method="post" action="mailer.php"> and mailer.php has the code I included above. Does this answer your question? If not, please let me know how I can answer it correctly.

Comment: As per my understanding, you are receiving http response code 500. i.e Internal server error. That error must be in the file which you are calling from the ajax. I can see you are using `url:$(form).attr('action')`. Technically this is the URL you are calling right ?

Comment: I guess. The mailer.php and app.js originally came from Github, so I didn't write all of it. I changed the mailer.php to include the reCAPTCHA, but I didn't change the app.js. It was all working before I made the changes in the mailer.php.

Comment: It looks like you have some syntax error in the file you are calling. If you could show the file you are calling then it would be easy to find the error.

Comment: Well, again I am confident that there's some syntax error in mailer.php

Comment: Do you mean the mailer.php or the app.js? I included both of them in my original post above. I'll edit it to make it clear. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: 500 error means there's an error in the PHP script. Check your PHP error log, it will tell you exactly where the error is.

Comment: Yes, checking error log is the best option.

Comment: What's there in the action attribute of your form ? is it `inc/autoload.php` ? Then check `inc/autoload.php`. Either the file contains the syntax error, or you are using older version of PHP in which some functions are not understood by the server.

Comment: As you told it was working before right ? You can trace down your changes. There you'll find your error.

Comment: @Nandan The action attribute of the form is calling mailer.php, and mailer.php requires autoload.php. I tried tracing the changes, but I can't figure it out. The error log says "Class 'ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha' not found" in my mailer.php. Is something wrong with the autoload.php that defines the class? It doesn't say anything about the autoload.php itself. I edited my original code above so that it includes the autoload.php..

Comment: It means, the path is wrong. Try reCaptcha class inside ReCaptcha folder? The place it's `require`d try to locate the file.

Comment: What do you mean? What exactly should I try? I have the autoload.php file, but what should I do with it? The error log doesn't say it can't find the file (it did that before, but then I added a slash so that it's "require_once __DIR__ . '/inc/autoload.php';" now). My current default PHP version is 5.5. Should I change it to 5.6?

Comment: I didn't use a composer. Could the issue be there?

Comment: Could someone explain why this was downvoted? What did I do wrong? I would like to know so I can do it better in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I fixed it. One reason it wasn't working was that I had to enable allow_url_fopen in php.ini.

Then I completely changed the code to get rid of that autoload.php and the class error. I didn't change app.js. The working mailer.php now looks like this:

```
<?php
// If the form was submitted
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    // If the Google Recaptcha box was clicked
    if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
        $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=MYKEY&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        $obj = json_decode($response);

        // If the Google Recaptcha check was successful
        if($obj->success == true) {
          $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
          $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
          $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
          $message = trim($_POST["message"]);
          if ( empty($name) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            http_response_code(400);
            echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
            exit;
          }
          $recipient = "I-removed-this@for-now.com";
          $subject = "New message from $name";
          $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
          $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
          $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";
          $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";
          if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
            http_response_code(200);
            echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
          } 

          else {
            http_response_code(500);
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong, and we couldn't send your message. Check your email address.";
          }

      } 

      // If the Google Recaptcha check was not successful    
      else {
        echo "Robot verification failed. Please try again.";
      }

  } 

  // If the Google Recaptcha box was not clicked   
  else {
    echo "Please click the reCAPTCHA box.";
  }      

} 

// If the form was not submitted
// Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.         
else {
  http_response_code(403);
  echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
}      
?>
```